# Evaluating a function call manually in Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define remove-leftmost
    (lambda (item ls)
       (cond
          ((null? ls) '())
          ((equal? (car ls) item) (cdr ls))
           (pair? (car ls))
            (let ((rem-list (remove-leftmost item (car ls)))
            (cons rem-list (cond
                                   ((equal? (car ls) rem-list)
                                    (remove-leftmost item (cdr ls)))
                                     (else (cdr ls))))))
       (else (cons (car ls) (remove-leftmost item (cdr ls)))))))
```

Now evaluate (remove-leftmost 'b (a (b c) (c (b a)))):

```
(cons a (remove-leftmost 'b ((b c) (c (b a)))))
(cons a (cons (c) ((c (b a)))))
(cons a ((c)(c (b a))))
(a (c)(c (b a)))
```

Does the evaluation work? If not, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to ident your code. After pasting your code into DrRacket and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> it's very obvious there are many errors in your code:

```
(define remove-leftmost
  (lambda (item ls)
    (cond
      ((null? ls) '())
      ((equal? (car ls) item) (cdr ls))
      (pair? (car ls)) 
      (let ((rem-list (remove-leftmost item (car ls)))
            (cons rem-list (cond
                             ((equal? (car ls) rem-list)
                              (remove-leftmost item (cdr ls)))
                             (else (cdr ls))))))
      (else (cons (car ls) (remove-leftmost item (cdr ls)))))))
```

When the two first terms are not met you have the value `pair?` as a predicate expression.The rest of the terms are never tried since `pair?` is always true, thus `(car ls)` is the most likely outcome of your procedure (Scheme does not have functions).

Just trying to guess I think the code perhaps should have looked like this:

```
(define remove-leftmost
  (lambda (item ls)
    (cond
      ((null? ls) '())
      ((equal? (car ls) item) (cdr ls))
      ((pair? (car ls)) 
       (let ((rem-list (remove-leftmost item (car ls))))
         (cons rem-list
               (cond
                 ((equal? (car ls) rem-list)
                  (remove-leftmost item (cdr ls)))
                 (else (cdr ls))))))
      (else
       (cons (car ls) 
             (remove-leftmost item (cdr ls)))))))

(remove-leftmost 'b '(a (b c) (c (b a))))
; ==> (a (c) (c (b a)))
```

I have put some linefeeds in as well as DrRacket has idented it according to the code. Notice the extra parentheses which are almost invisible to humans but not to IDEs that formats such code.

Comment: I copied the program off of my textbook. Can you point out which parts are wrong? I might've copied them incorrectly.

Comment: @user134627 You are sure you copied the parentheses correctly? Usually `(pair? (car lsr))` is a predicate and not just `pair?` which it now is since it lacks parentheses.

Comment: @ Sylwwester, yes, opening parenthesis is missing there where you pointed it out. That was incorrectly copied.

Comment: @user134627 I urge you to use an IDE when copying. You'll notice the error right away since the indentation becomes off.

Comment: @ Sywester, I just ran the newly indented code in repl and it works. What about the function call evaluation?

Comment: @user134627 compare your expression with my example you'll see you have forgot a single quote. WIthout it you'll get that `a` is not a procedure. Everytime you want something to be data you'll need to quote it.